# Tiny Slider - add/remove slides dynamically

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add and removes slides from a slider using [Tiny Slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider) like you can with [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)?

I've figured out a way to target the current slide and delete it using the active class Tiny Slider applies and a data attribute. And was going to reverse the process to add slides back in.

However, the active class that Tiny Slider applies doesn't shift to the next available slide, making me think adding/removing on the fly isn't possible.

Here's my current setup:

```
const sliderWrapper = document.querySelector('.slider');
const sliderNav = document.querySelector('.slider-nav');

const slider = tns({
    container: sliderWrapper,
    items: 1,
    slideBy: 'page',
    autoplay: false,
    navContainer: sliderNav,
    controls: false,
    loop: false
});

const deleteSlide = document.querySelector('.delete');

deleteSlide.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const currentSlideWithSlider = document.querySelector('.tns-slide-active').dataset.slide;
    const allSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

    allSlides.forEach(function(slide, index){
        const currentSlideNoSlider = slide.dataset.slide;
        if(currentSlideWithSlider === currentSlideNoSlider) {
            slide.parentNode.removeChild(slide);
        }
    });
    slider.destroy;
    slider.rebuild;
});
```

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/042e5f790a3fbfaefd616c2882a0822a

Thanks for any help.